# Common database patch for multiple databases

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I am working on a application that needs to support as many as five databases now while only MSSQL and MYSQL were the two supported databases earlier. Although the connection are managed through a properties file that provides information about the database, the SQL scripts are managed separately for each of the supported database. Each version involves some addition or deletion of master data and alterations in the database schema(rarely). We had been managing this using two sets of queries(one each for MSSQL and MYSQL). Since we need to add support for three more databases- managing five separate patch files (the approach we were using earlier) will be a cumbersome task and would also require 5 times the effort as far as testing is concerned.

I need to find a way to manage these patches using hibernate. I wonder what could be the best approach to make the database patch independent and inter operable between databases. Please suggest

Comment: Have an entity manager for each database.

Comment: can u explain this a bit further.

Comment: In your persistance.XML you will have setup for each database. Using that create entityManagers for every config. Then using that create more entity managers. How were you dealing with two existing MSSQL and MYSQL.

Comment: I think what you are talking about is related to managing two datasources.....whereas my concern is managing sql queries that are required for backward compatibility and adding some master data

Comment: Yes that might be the case. Can you elaborate more ? Edit your question. You do realize that one entity manager can deal with one driver i.e. one version of database. One driver might work on different versions of databases thus abstracting out the implementation of dealing with different versions for you.

Comment: Hi Shahzeb, I have modified the question. Help me if u can in this  regard

Comment: Hibernate can add tables and columns db agnostic using the schema classes used by schemaexport/update. It can not drop columns however. datamanipulation can be achieved backwardcompatible with entitymode.map which uses dictionaries instead of entities.